# Customisation : Public Knowledge for Mobile, Web and Facebook - version 3

Tags: visualforce, appexchange

We have installed Public Knowledge for Mobile, Web and Facebook - version 3 from https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000059QxXEAU.

Though we have configured the PKB . But we are struggling with the article display format.

We want to display the articles in same page where as in current package it is navigating to next page on click of title.

It appears that the application uses some special Salesforce-native renderer when displaying articles. When rendering an article, it uses a special URL format that seemingly calls hidden functionality to render the article.

Please let us know if someone is having prior knowledge or experience of working on the PKB customization.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am also looking for, how exactly can we do it.

Comment: I wasn't able to customise it much . So I created my own PKB. :)